# Handling Optional .NET DataSource Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

What is the standard way to implement optional query parameters in a .NET WinForms application?

In other words, only query on a field if the value of a corresponding control is not null.

Note: Prefer VB.NET answers (C# okay too)

**EDIT:** I use a FillBy method which calls a query in my Access database.  In the TableAdapter query editor, I just used `WHERE (field1 = ?) AND (field2 = ?) ...`  I just can't find the "hook" to bind form controls to the  table adapter query parameters and so that if a form uses the default value to not query on it.

Comment: That depends greatly on how you access your database. Do you use stored procedures? How do you call those stored procedures from within your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply LINQ `Where` clause many times.
If you're working with a `DataSet`, you can call `AsEnumerable` (available since .NET 3.5) to do LINQ queries on it.

Comment: I have a DataGridView which binds to the BindingSource for the Access query.  Can I do this using only the designer?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. It's easily done with code though (and is a better practice than designer drag-drop-ouch).

Comment: With the LINQ approach... do I just fill the `TableAdapter` without any conditions?  Then, query using LINQ and put those results into my `DataGridView`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This will not be awesome if you have *a lot* of rows because the filtering occurs in memory, not in the database. Try it out and see if it fits for you.

Comment: Well, I'm just starting out, so I don't know how it will scale over time.  Do you have a database filtering solution?

Comment: Well, you can totally drop `DataSet`s and work with ORM like LINQ to SQL or Dapper.

Answer (score 2):

My Access syntax is rusty, so you might have to adjust it, but you can try something like this:

```
WHERE (@Field1 IS NOT NULL AND Field1 = @Field1) AND (@Field2 IS NOT NULL AND Field2 = @Field2)
```